# How to avoid fragment recreation using navigation architecture component?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation, back-stack

I have 4 fragments in a drawer, lets call them fragment **A, B, C, D**. I use navigation architecture to bind my fragments with the drawer.

**Fragment A is my entry point** and from there I can navigate anywhere on the drawer.

Suppose I take the path **A > B > C > B > C**

If I press back from C, it goes to B then to C again and then to B and finally to A, but I don't want that.

When I press the back button from C, I want it to just go back to B then A without recreating fragments that are already in the back stack. Can someone please help on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Then stop using fragments and navigation arch ... and make your own based on views ... This is how fragments work and you can do nothing with this

Answer (score 0):

> When I press the back button from C, I want it to just go back to B
> then A without recreating fragments that are already in the back
> stack.

When you are navigating to a destination, you can pop the old instance of the destination from the back stack. Just add the pop inclusive to all your `action` in nav graph.

```
<!-- Add this in the actions navigating to B -->
app:popUpTo="@id/B" 
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

**Explanation**

What the above pop behavior will do is, when you are navigating from, say **C > B**, it will pop everything till B (inclusive) from the back stack and add the latest instance of B on the back stack.

**A > B > C > B > C** will have a back stack:

```
A
A, B
A, B, C
A, B
A, B, C
```

**Note:**
The inherent assumption here is that this is not a valid case in your example.
**A > B > C > D > B > C** leads to a back tracking of **C > B > D > A**. Please be aware that in the above solution when you navigate to second B, it will pop out D from you back stack too!

Comment: I agree with you except using navigation components in drawer doesn't have actions tied to it. The drawer does the fragment switching by itself